# Getting file crunching failed Error after adding 9 patch image to project

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm getting below error when I add this 9 patch image to drawable folder.

```
Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

According to Android Studio 9 patch editor I don't have any bad patches in my image so image is correct.

[image]

I did some searching and tried following solution. But still no luck.

1. Changed Project location to avoid 256 characters limit for project path.
2. Added aaptOptions `cruncherEnabled = false`
3. Invalidate caches/restart

Using 9 patch images always cause headache, are there any other alternatives for this?